# Doctrine, ralation ManyToOne

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

When a try update my database I got error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`symfony`.`#sql-d8c_55`, CONSTRAINT `FK_957A6479A233CB39` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`klient_id`) REFERENCES `klient` (`id`))

My class user:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Class User
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table("fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Klient", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $klient;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getKlient()
    {
        return $this->klient;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $klient
     */
    public function setKlient($klient)
    {
        $this->klient = $klient;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
}
```

class Klient

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Klient
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="klient")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\KlientRepository")
 */
class Klient
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nazwa", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $nazwa;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="klient")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nazwa
     *
     * @param string $nazwa
     *
     * @return Klient
     */
    public function setNazwa($nazwa)
    {
        $this->nazwa = $nazwa;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nazwa
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNazwa()
    {
        return $this->nazwa;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your code related to persisting these entities. Doctrine doesn't automatically persist relationships (unless configured to do so), so it's likely that's the cause, but we'll know more when you add that code.

Comment: ok, I edit my post

Comment: What code do you have that actually persists the entities? I see the entity classes, but nothing that does anything with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion you have this error because you already have datas in your database. When you try to add the foreign key on your user table, kcient_id is null. And in your definition, you specify nullable: false.

I suggest you proceed in two times.

1. Edit your annotation to nullable: true, update your database and link your client to klient
2. Re-edit your annotation to nullable: false, it should be ok